# How to get two files from the terminal to be used by a class (as in java.io.File)

Tags: java, file

So I am taking two files (txt most likely) and passing them to a class via the terminal which then will be used as inputs and scanned with a buffered reader. I am however having difficulty finding out how to do this in the sense of through the terminal and not just calling the file names indiscriminately in the code.

The end result of the call should look like this

```
java <class> fileA.txt fileB.txt
```

or

```
java <class> desktop/FileA.txt documents/fileB.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use args massive like this:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
   if (args.length < 2) throw new RuntimeException("Want 2 Args!");
   File file1=new File(args[0]);
   File file2=new File(args[1]);
}
```

Comment: Would I (as in the above answer) have to specify the files being passed after the declaration of the class name? And what if only one file was being passed to the constructor? How would I deal with this continuing the use of the program but with only one file passed

Comment: Yes, you need to specify it after the class (or after the `-jar main.jar`). You can use args.length to see how many args there are.

Comment: Ahh I see. So I would still need to say 2 files can be passed but in the instance that only one is passed I can just specify what to do in this case and the unused instance of fileB for instance would not cause any issue?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use the < operator to use the file as input:

```
java <class> < file.ext
```

To pass more than one file, you will need to do the way you are doing and manipulate the parameters inside your code.

```
java <class> file1.ext file2.ext

public static void main( String[] args ) {
    // args[0] will contain the String "file1.ext"
    // args[1] will contain the String "file2.ext"
}
```

Comment: Confused as what you mean? And also how can I manipulate the files passed here in the actual class itself